# How to display filename for custom input in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a styled file input. It works fine, but after the file selection, I would like to show the selected filename instead of `No files selected`. How can I do this in Vue?

```css
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #8181fe;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

form input, textarea {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d9dadc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #393645;
  resize: none;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: -8px;
} 

.file-info {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #a9a7a9;
  line-height: 53px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="section-file">
      <label class="fileContainer">
        Select files
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" id="file" name="file" accept="jpg/image/jpeg/image/png">
      </label>

      <span class="file-info">No files selected</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the [`change` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)'s target is the associated `<input>`, and the selected files are indicated in [`<input>.files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files), which has a `length` property for the number of files. We could then track the non-zero length as a Boolean to determine whether to display `No files selected`:

1. Add a `files` data property to track the selected [files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#files):

```js
data() {
  return {
    files: null
  }
},
```

2. Use [`v-if`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) to conditionally render `No files selected` based on `files` above. In the `v-else` branch, we display the list of selected files:

```html
<span v-if="!files || !files.length">No files selected</span>
<ul v-else>
  <li v-for="file in files" :key="file.name">{{file.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

3. Add a `change`-[event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers) to the `<input>` in the component's template:

```html
<input @change="filesSelected">
```

4. Define the handler method in the component's `methods`:

```js
methods: {
  fileSelected(e) {
    this.files = e.target.files
  }
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#contact-form',
  data() {
    return {
      files: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    fileSelected(e) {
      this.files = e.target.files
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.fileContainer {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #8181fe;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 6px 18px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

form input, textarea {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #d9dadc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #393645;
  resize: none;
}

.fileContainer [type=file] {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  text-align: right;
  top: -8px;
} 

.file-info {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #a9a7a9;
  line-height: 53px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="contact-form" class="contact-form">
  <form class="form">
    <div class="section-file">

      <label class="fileContainer">
        Select files
        <input type="file" class="file-upload" id="file" name="file" @change="fileSelected" multiple accept="image/jpg,image/jpeg,/image/png">
      </label>

      <span class="file-info" v-if="!files || !files.length">No files selected</span>
      <ul v-else>
        <li v-for="file in files" :key="file.name">{{file.name}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this code is if i change the file the system keep showing the old file

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz What do you mean by "change the file"? Can you create a new question with a reproducible sample?

Comment: My english isnt the best, but ill try to explain better:

The page loads, you choose a file, but you change your mind and you choose a different file. Well the name file showed is the old name, the name dosent change.

Comment: @Luis That's unrelated to the code suggested in this answer, and it's more likely a bug in your own implementation. As you can see from the demo in the code snippet above, selecting a new file causes an update in the filename shown in the list. We can help you troubleshoot the problem if you post a new question with a reproducible demo.

Comment: Yes, you right, for some reason after restart my computer it works, thank you!